# Javascript - How can I build a sentence to display data based on whether data values are > 0?

Tags: javascript, object

I am getting back data from an API - just an object with numerical values pertaining to each key - and then building a simple sentence to display the data for the user. However, I only want to include a value from the data if it is bigger than 0. Here is an example with mock data:

```js
let data = {red: 100, blue: 200, yellow: 0, green: 400};

let resultsSentence = `We found ${data.red} red posts, ${data.blue} blue posts, and ${data.green} green posts.`

console.log(resultsSentence)
```

As you can see, I left yellow out from the results sentence because it has a value of `0`. Of course, I need to be able to generate this sentence dynamically based on whatever data is returned. If I use conditionals, it will be a mess, since there are too many possible scenarios (writing 15 if/else statements does not seem like a good approach).

How can I handle this? I need to generate the sentence based on whichever values are `> 0`. At first I thought, easy, I'll just push all the values into an array, check for 0's, and remove any items that are equal to 0 from the array. Then, build the sentence based on however long the array is, i.e., if the array length is `3`, then refer to each value as `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`. However, this presents a problem, since I need to be able to clarify *which values are which* in the sentence.  For example, if I remove `yellow` from the array, the array length will be `3`, but I won't know *which* value was removed.

Can anyone help me come up with an efficient solution for this?

Comment: A `switch` statement would be more compact than `if/else`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus can you elaborate on how I would employ a switch statement here? What would the condition be?

Comment: @marcdubbles here is a working codepen https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/QWQxNga

Comment: From not accepted solution on my part, can I ask what framework you are using?

Comment: @markdubbles no framework, just vanilla JS.  I can use jQuery if that's useful, but no other framework or library ideally.

Comment: Ok. So you want the behavior of dynamically updated state (across the application) but don't have a custom library and don't want to use an available library? If so, then there is no solution.

Comment: @mardubbles thanks but as you can see from the accepted answer, that is no the case.

Comment: @MickeyVershbow I see, I see. Output looks the same as my answer, but I'll leave it alone.

Comment: @mardubbles you are missing the point though -- your answer didn't address the issue of dynamically updating data. The output for accepted answer looks the same as yours, except it works no matter what values are returned in the data. Your answer only works for the specific data values I provided in example, the whole point of the question was how to handle dynamically updating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over the object's keys and values, building up your string inside of it.

This does result in an [oxford comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/) but you can strip that in the conditional (where you choose to use `and` instead).

```js
let data = {red: 100, blue: 200, yellow: 0, green: 400};
let res = 'We found '

// Keep a record of how many keys we've processed so we know when we're at the end
let i = 1
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
  // we could just continue early here, but we want to keep adding to `i`
  if (v > 0) { 
    // This is the last key so use `and` not a comma
    if (i === Object.keys(data).length) {
      res += `and ${v} ${k} posts.`
    } else {
      res += `${v} ${k} posts, `
    }
  }
  i++
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: this is brilliant - thank you so much - really helpful and I learned a lot!

Comment: Or just not include the posts in the object that are zero, and use native javascript expressions. But I see how adding "and" here would change things.

Comment: @mardubbles not sure what you're getting at here?  The data object is returned from the API. Simply looping through and removing items with value of 0 would not help me here, as I explained in my post.

Comment: @Cjmarkham  this is the accepted answer because it includes a period at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let data = {red: 100, blue: 200, yellow: 0, green: 400};

let str = [];
let len = Object.keys(data).length;
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val], index) => {
    let isLast = (len - 1 == index) && str.length > 0;
    if(val > 0) str.push((isLast ? 'and ' : '') + `${val} ${key} posts`);
})

let resultsSentence = 'We found ' + str.join(', ')
console.log(resultsSentence)
```

Comment: great solution,  I think this works similarly to the accepted answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this (without depedencies)

```
const keys = Object.keys(data)
const values = Object.values(data)
let string = 'we found'

values.map((item, index)=>{
  if(item > 0){
        string += ` ${item} ${keys[index]} posts,`
  }
})
console.log(string.slice(0,-1)+'.')
```

try with lodash as

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let data = {red: 100, blue: 200, yellow: 0, green: 400};
let string = 'we found'

_.map(data,(value,key)=>{
  if(value > 0){
    string += ` ${value} ${key} posts,`
  }
})
console.log(string.slice(0,-1)+'.')
```

Comment: thanks interesting approach here. My boss doesn't like dependencies so I am trying to solve this with vanilla JS.  I wonder if I could employ a similar approach without lodash, although I can't map over an object...

Comment: @MickeyVershbow can you check now

Comment: This is great! So helpful! I've never had to write a solution like this - but your approach makes sense - thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Could be you have an outdated browser.

I tested your code on Chrome Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```js
let data = {red: 100, blue: 200, yellow: 0, green: 400};

let resultsSentence = `We found ${data.red} red posts, ${data.blue} blue posts, and ${data.green} green posts.`

console.log(resultsSentence);
```

And got this result:

```
We found 100 red posts, 200 blue posts, and 400 green posts.
```

So unless I don't understand your question, there are no errors when we include the object of `data` to access its properties.

Let me know.

Comment: @marcdubbles thanks so much. Sorry my question must not be clear. The data is going to update dynamically -- in some instances yellow will return `0`, in other instances, yellow will be `> 0`  but green and red will return `0`, etc. 

I am trying to write code that dynamically generates the sentence based on whichever values are NOT zero.

Comment: Oh ok. Well that changes things (on my thinking). I will have a relook.